# How can I resolve GIT conflicts in Webmatrix 3?

Tags: git, conflict, webmatrix

I'm using Webmatrix3 and GIT on a project with another developer.
Now we have a conflict on a file.
I've resolved it, but I can't find a command in Webmatrix GUI to let GIT accept my resolved version of the file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resolving a conflict means:

- modifying a file
- add, commit (local)
- push to remote

That means (from "[How to use Git in WebMatrix](http://www.microsoft.com/web/post/how-to-use-git-in-webmatrix)"):

- once you have resolved the conflict, you need to add and commit with Webmatrix3:
  [image: http://webblogheart.blob.core.windows.net/files/clip_image002_thumb_18.png]
- Then push:
  [image: http://webblogheart.blob.core.windows.net/files/clip_image009_thumb_13.png]